# debug child process running under control of entr

Tags: python, macos, pdb, python-sockets

I'm trying to find a way to use [remote_pdb](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-remote-pdb/) and [entr](http://entrproject.org/) together as an environment for rapid testing and development of Python 3 multiprocessing applications, but they're not playing nicely together.

Consider the trivial test case below:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from remote_pdb import RemotePdb
def child():
    RemotePdb('localhost', 4444).set_trace()
    while True:
        print("I am the child")
        time.sleep(1)
proc = Process(target=child)
proc.start()
proc.join()
```

If I save it in a file, say, 'mp.py' and the run it with:

`python mp.py`

it works very nicely. It breaks, as expected, in the child process displaying

```
CRITICAL:root:RemotePdb session open at 127.0.0.1:4444, waiting for connection ...
RemotePdb session open at 127.0.0.1:4444, waiting for connection ...
```

and I can connect from another terminal session with, netcat or socat and use the python debugger. Exiting the debugger leaves the child and parent running until I explicitly kill them.

If I now comment out the RemotePdb() call and run the script under control of `entr` with

```
ls mp.py | entr -r python mp.py
```

it allows me to edit mp.py and get an automatic clean restart each time I save.

*The problem arises when I uncomment the RemotePdb() call.*

The script is restarted by entr and it breaks in the child displaying the same 'waiting for connection' message as before but if I try to connect with `netcat` in another terminal window the pdb session is unresponsive with no output and no echo -- just empty lines in response to CR's. I get the same result with `socat`.

I'm developing on OS X 10.11.6 with python 3.5.3, entr 3.7, remote_pdb 1.2.

**What I'm asking for:**
I'll accept an answer that provides a command line solution which combines the benefits of `entr` and `remote_pdb` or a clear explanation why it can't be done.

Thanks!

**Update**
Further testing shows that the `-r` (restart) option to entr is necessary to produce the problem, i.e.

```
ls mp.py | entr python mp.py
```

permits the debugger connection to work. Unfortunately, the restart option is essential to the workflow.

**Update 2**: The problem seems to be related to setting the process group.  This is done by `entr -r` to make sure all the child processes can be killed.  While trying to come up with a Python script to replace `entr` I found that calling `os.setpgrp()` in the parent process will produce the same failure (no I/O to debugger) if the script is launched from an IPython shell (`!python mp.py`) but not if it launched from `bash`.

**Update 3**: The author of remote_pdb and I have independently verified that the problem is not occurring in Linux. This is an OS X issue apparently having something to do with Python sockets and process groups. I've added to the tags accordingly.

Comment: Downvoting without leaving an explanatory comment is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It's an old OS X python issue that has either crept back in or was never fixed in Pdb. The fix is to set up to ignore SIGTTOU before importing readline. See http://bugs.python.org/issue14892 for details.

I cured the problem by patching my  local copy of pdb.Pdb as shown below.

```
class Pdb(bdb.Bdb, cmd.Cmd):

    _previous_sigint_handler = None

    def __init__(self, completekey='tab', stdin=None, stdout=None, skip=None,
                 nosigint=False):
        bdb.Bdb.__init__(self, skip=skip)
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self, completekey, stdin, stdout)
        if stdout:
            self.use_rawinput = 0
        self.prompt = '(Pdb) '
        self.aliases = {}
        self.displaying = {}
        self.mainpyfile = ''
        self._wait_for_mainpyfile = False
        self.tb_lineno = {}
        # Try to load readline if it exists
        try:
############ FIX OSX BUG ######################################
            import sys
            if sys.platform == 'darwin':
                import signal
                signal.signal(signal.SIGTTOU, signal.SIG_IGN)
############ END FIX ##########################################
            import readline
            # remove some common file name delimiters
            readline.set_completer_delims(' \t\n`@#$%^&*()=+[{]}\\|;:\'",<>?')
        except ImportError:
            pass
```

Many thanks to [ionelmc](https://github.com/ionelmc), author of `remote_pdb` and `hunter` for generous help tracking down the problem.